# How do I disable excerpts on blogs and website

Tags: excerpt

I want to disable the excerpt from showing in blog and entire website in **functions.php** file.

This didn't work

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`remove_post_type_support()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support) in your `functions.php` like that:

```
/**
 * Remove unwanted features.
 */
add_action('init', 'my_theme_remove_post_type_support');
function my_theme_remove_post_type_support() {
  remove_post_type_support('post', 'excerpt');
}
```